# what's the diff b/t protractor and specflow?

Tags: angular, protractor, cucumber, specflow, gherkin

What's the diff b/t Protractor and Specflow? I used SpecFlow over 5 years ago so I'm a bit rusty on the tech and concepts. Is Protractor the same type of tool as SpecFlow? Do they both use Selenium and Cucumber/Gherkin?

Answer (score 1):

**Protractor is not Behaviour Driven Development framework it is testing tool just like Selenium and can be used with BDD Frameworks like SpecFlow. Here is explanation for both:**

**Protractor** is an end-to-end test framework for Angular and AngularJS applications. 
Protractor is wrapper of Selenium so You get features of Selenium and plus You got some features from protractor:

- Protractor supports Angular-specific locator strategies, which allows you to test Angular-specific elements without any setup effort on your part.
- You no longer need to add waits and sleeps to your test. Protractor can automatically execute the next step in your test the moment the webpage finishes pending tasks, so you don’t have to worry about waiting for your test and webpage to sync.

**SpecFlow** is a testing framework which supports Behaviour Driven Development (BDD). It lets us define application behaviour in plain meaningful English text using a simple grammar defined by a language called Gherkin. Specflow can be used with Selenium and Protractor also and here is great article about it 
https://anthonychu.ca/post/end-to-end-testing-angular-apps-with-nunit-and-specflow-using-protractornet/